# Converting POX to SOAP message in WSO2

Tags: wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I'm using a gateway API in WSO2 ESB in order to adapt incoming requests to my back-end service. The back-end service accept only POX messages with a predefined format. I want to give clients the ability to send SOAP requests in order to retreive information from my back-end service.

I'm intending to use payloadfactory mediator but i'm not sure if it is the best solution.

My typical back-end request is like follow :

```html
<methodCall>
<member>
<name>ABC</name>
<value>abc</value>
</member>
<member>
<name>XYZ</name>
<value>xyz</value>
</member>
</methodCall>
```

And i want to be sent to my API like follow :

```html
<soap:body>
<ABC>abc</ABC>
<XYZ>xyz</XYZ>
</soap:body>
```

in other words, a  in my POX request represent an object with a "name" and a "value" and i want to write it in SOAP as "name"(value)"/name".

Can you help please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a payload factory to create the new message and a 'send'  with format="soap11" to add the soap envelope.
It will look something like this:

```
    <inSequence>
      <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
            <format>
            <test>
                <ABC>$1</ABC>
                <XYZ>$2</XYZ>
            </test>
            </format>
            <args>
                <arg expression="//value[0]"/>
                <arg expression="//value[1]"/>
            </args>
      </payloadFactory>

      <send>
        <endpoint>
           <address format="soap11"  uri="http://youruri" />
        </endpoint>
      </send>
   </inSequence>
```

Comment: Hi jan, i will try it and return to you ASAP. But, it seems like it is a static solution and its not compatible with other use cases. In other words, can i detect dynamically the node ABC and put it in my soap message? something like this :

Comment: You can use xslt to dynamically create your message. Take a look at for instance: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qM2e2f/1 and https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI640/XSLT+Mediator

Answer (score 0):

> it seems like it is a static solution and its not compatible with other use cases. In other words, can i detect dynamically the node ABC and put it in my soap message?

You cannot achieve this requirement using the payload factory (PF) mediator, because you cannot create a payload like below inside the PF.

```
<$1>$2</$1>
```

It will return **an Unexpected character '$' in prolog, after '<'** error when you create a payload like that.

So there are 2 options to achieve this requirement:

1. Using an XSLT mediator, refer to [1]
2. Implement custom class mediator, refer to [2]

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI650/XSLT+Mediator

[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI650/Class+Mediator